# C Search for string in heap array

Tags: arrays, c, char, malloc, heap-memory

I use the following code to load a large hashtable on the heap.
However i dont know the right syntax to search the whole array after loading.

I suppose i can add a strcmp in the last J loop??

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int lines_allocated = 128;
    int max_line_len = 100;

    /* Allocate lines of text */
    char **words = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char*)*lines_allocated);
    if (words==NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Out of memory (1).\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    FILE *fp = fopen("hashtable.txt", "r");

    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Error opening file.\n");
        exit(2);
    }

    int i;

    for (i = 0; 1; i++)
    {
        int j;

        /* Have we gone over our line allocation? */
        if (i >= lines_allocated)
        {
            int new_size;

            /* Double our allocation and re-allocate */
            new_size = lines_allocated*2;
            words = (char **)realloc(words,sizeof(char*)*new_size);

            if (words == NULL)
            {
                fprintf(stderr,"Out of memory.\n");
                exit(3);
            }

            lines_allocated = new_size;
        }

        /* Allocate space for the next line */
        words[i] = malloc(max_line_len);

        if (words[i] == NULL)
        {
            fprintf(stderr,"Out of memory (3).\n");
            exit(4);
        }

        if (fgets(words[i], max_line_len-1,fp) == NULL)
            break;

        /* Get rid of CR or LF at end of line */
        for (j = strlen(words[i]) - 1; j >= 0 && (words[i][j] == '\n' || words[i][j] == '\r')j--);
            words[i][j] = '\0';
        }

    int j;
    for(j = 0; j < i; j++)
    printf("%s\n", words[j]);
    // Search for a string e.g "ffffffffff999999999922222222227777777777" in words[]
    //
    //strcmp ( string, words[j])????
    //
    //
    //
    /* Good practice to free memory */

    for (;i>=0;i--)
        free(words[i]);

    free(words);

    return 0;
}
```

i have tried to implement strcmp in the loop but then the program segfaults.
Used this example :

```
/* what is i? the number of items used in the array? */
for(x = 0; x < i; x++) {
    if ( strcmp( new_name, names[x] ) == 0 ){
        /* match, x is the index */
        return x;
    }
}
/* here with no match */
return -1;
```

Comment: Please avoid stuff like `for (j=strlen(words[i])-1;j>=0 && (words[i][j]=='\n' || words[i][j]=='\r')j--);`. It's unreadable.

Answer (score 1):

As i was indenting your code i saw:

`for (j = strlen(words[i]) - 1; j >= 0 && (words[i][j] == '\n' || words[i][j] == '\r')j--);`

I think you meant:

`for (j = strlen(words[i]) - 1; j >= 0 && (words[i][j] == '\n' || words[i][j] == '\r'); j--)`

`----^^^^^^^`

That while would never execute what it had between braces.

Comment: This answer should be a comment.

Comment: If this is the root cause of the problem, then it's a valid answer (but the question should be closed as a typo)

Comment: @MichaelWalz It was a little too lengthy to put it at a comment and i wanted to show where the problem was.

Answer (score 1):

**You have a problem here:**

```
for (j=strlen(words[i]) - 1; j>=0 && (words[i][j]=='\n' || words[i][j]=='\r'); j--);
words[i][j]='\0';
```

`j` is off by one. You shoud increment `j`just after the loop:

```
for (j=strlen(words[i])-1; j>=0 && (words[i][j]=='\n' || words[i][j]=='\r'); j--)
{
}

words[i][j + 1] = '\0';
```

The extra `{ }` is there only for readibility purposes. Otherwise if you forget the `;` after the `for`, your code will compile correctly but with `words[i][j +1 ]='\0';` being part of the loop.

**Other off by one problem:**

You must decrement `i` here:

```
/* Good practice to free memory */
i-- ;  // <<<< decrement i here
for (;i>=0;i--)
  free(words[i]);
```

**Problem with strcmp:**

Concerning your `strcmp` problem you probably want this:

```
int j;
for(j = 0; j < i; j++)
{
  printf("%s\n", words[j]);

  if (strcmp (words[j], "word we are lookong for") == 0)
  {
     // found it
  }
}
```